# Remove duplicates based on a value from a different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery, aggregate-functions

In MS Visual Studio, I have following table 1, where I want to remove duplicate caseNum based on PrimIndicator column. If case number has a duplicate caseNum, I want to keep the row with "True" PrimIndicator, if caseNum is not duplicate then keep the CaseNum.

Table1:

```
ID  CaseNum PrimIndicator
1   AAA-123 TRUE
2   AAA-123 FALSE
3   BBB-546 
4   CCC-753 TRUE
5   CCC-753 
6   ABC-347 
7   DEF-546 TRUE
8   DEF-346
```

Want Table2:

```
ID  CaseNum PrimIndicator
1   AAA-123 TRUE
3   BBB-546 
4   CCC-753 TRUE
6   ABC-347 
7   DEF-546 TRUE
```

So far I have tried this but it seems that max() function is not working if the PrimIndicator is blank.

```
Select ID, distinct CaseNum, Max(PrimIndicator)
from Table1
group by CaseNum, PrimIndicator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one row per `casenum`, I would suggest `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by casenum
                                order by case when primeindicator = 'true' then 1 else 2 end
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This *guarantees* one row per `casenum` in the result set.

Given your data, you could also use `where` logic:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.primeindicator = 'true' or 
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.casenum = t.casenum and
                        t2.primeindicator = 'true'
                 );
```

This does not guarantee one row per `casenum` -- but it does work for the data you have provided.

Comment: @Sprt_Add . . . I answered this question because GMB's answer is not guaranteed to return exactly one row per `casenum`.  In particular, it filters out cases that have multiple rows but none with a `'true'` indicator.  That way my interpretation of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use window functions:

```
select *
from (select t.*, count(*) over(partition by casenum) cnt from table1 t) t
where t.primindicator = 'true' or cnt = 1
```